# send email with Js validation, php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a simple "contact me" form. 
Is made in html (of course), validate in Javascript than I use Ajax request and send all of it to a php file, where the form should be validated again and than send it. (i know just a bit of php so i hope is like that!)

The "success" or "not submit" message are in the html and displayed by ajax/js.
So my question is easy: How can i send the body to my personal email including the php validation? 
I show you my code:

Js/ajax:

```
myForm.submitForm = function(){
var formData = {
    name: myForm.name.val(),
    email: myForm.email.val(),
    text: myForm.text.val(),
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'contact.php',
    method: 'post',
    //dataType: 'json';
    success: myForm.submitSuccess,
    error: myForm.submitError
})
};

myForm.submitSuccess = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
myForm.succMess.html(data.message);
myForm.succMess.show();
};

myForm.errorSuccess = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
myForm.errorMess.html(textStatus);
myForm.errorMess.show();
};
```

Php:

```
<?php
   $nome = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $text = nl2br($_POST['text']);

    //mail() I guess i should use this one but how?!    

    //check if inputs are empty
if(!empty($nome) and !empty($email) and !empty($text)){
    $mail_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $mail_from = $email;
    $mail_subject = "Email sent by $nome";
    $mail_body = "$nome: $email. $text";

?>
```

Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: You will find most or all of your answers on the PHP.net Website http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php on the `mail()` function. If you want to send the `$mail_body`, just use `mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $headers);`

Comment: Plus your `mail();` would go under `$mail_body = "$nome: $email. $text";` and not under `$text = nl2br($_POST['text']);`

Comment: thanks for answering. Yes i already had a look to the official doc but i didn't understand. So you mean that I just need to write `mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $headers);` after `$mail_body` and that's all?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes something to that affect. However I suggest you use `&&` instead of `and`

Comment: Plus I did try your code and there's something in there that wasn't sending mail. Where did you get it from? I use my own version of Ajax handler with mail which works beautifully.

Comment: i just get the php part somewhere in internet eheh and than simplify for my self. About ajax i just wrote by my self. I don't have the chance to test it yet since i use MAMP and php doesn't work with it as far as i know. So you think the problem coming from Ajax request? Can i see yours?

Comment: The problem may very well be with your Ajax. I will find mine and post it as an answer shortly.

Comment: It is posted below. If you feel that it has answered your question with success, please accept by clicking the checkmark next to the answer till it turns green, that way your question will no longer be in the "unanswered" category.

Comment: So, any luck with my code?

Comment: Btw, I was looking for an example for someone asking a similar question and yours came up with my answer. You never accepted my answer to close it properly and asked you already. Yours is still considered as being unsolved, but mine did solve the question.

Comment: Funny that i was checking this post some days ago either.. i never accept because it never worked for me. I don't know if it worked for someone else..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to send mail via Ajax and jQuery.

### HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#success').hide(1);
        $.post("email_ajax.php", $("#contact").serialize(),  function(response) {
            $('#success').html(response);
            $('#success').show(1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<style>

html {
/*    height: 100%; */

height:auto;
}
body {
    background:#000;
/*  background: url(bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Proxima, sans-serif;;
}

#empty {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    height:150px;
    width:auto;
    background:none;
    border:none;
}

#contact ul{
    margin-left:10px;
    list-style:none;
}

#contact ul li{
    margin-left:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name"  width="250" size="35" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" width="250" size="35" required/>
    </li>
<br><br>
    <li>
        <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="40" required></textarea>
    </li>
    <li><input type="button" value=" SEND " id="submit" /><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
<div id="success" style="color: yellow;"></div></li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### email_ajax.php

**Note:** Change `$to = 'email@example.com';` to your Email address.

```
<?php
if((empty($_POST['name'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['message']))){
die("<b>ERROR!</b> All fields must be filled.");
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = strtolower($name);
$name = ucwords($name);

$to = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'Website message from: '.$name;
$message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nMessage: \n".$message;
$headers = 'From: email@example.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo "Thank you! Your email was sent $name.";
echo "<br>";
echo "This is the email you entered: <b>$email</b>";
}else{
// echo var_dump($_POST);
echo "<b>ERROR!</b> Invalid E-mail. Please provide a valid email address. Example: myEmail@example.com";
echo "<br>";
echo "The email <b>$email</b> you entered, is not valid.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Yey! Thank you, now i play a bit around and i will tell you the outcome :)

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta You're welcome. I guess you will accept it if and when it does work for you? It works for me, I shouldn't see why it would not for you. :)

Comment: Sorry for get back so late. I thought i already answered. Anyway thank man for you code, works good :) I just have some problem with $headers that in some how broke everything, but without it (that i don't need anyway) works great.

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer in order to close the question, cheers